# How do I zoom in/out in the web client? are there other clients?

Tags: neo4j

I have a large model and would like to see more than the default view shows.  How do I zoom in/out in the web client? are there other clients?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that you can zoom in/out the web client.  You do have a few options:

- You can go full-screen to give yourself some more real estate
- In Neo4j 2.2 you have the ability to drag the viewport to see more
- Also in Neo4j 2.2, you can click the download icon and download either a PNG or SVG.  This isn't interactive, obviously, but can be helpful

For larger views of your data, [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) and [Linkurious](https://linkurio.us/) can be helpful

In Neo4J 3.0.1 there are zoom buttons in the bottom-right hand side of the screen when maximized:

[image: Zoom buttons]

Comment: Neo4j 3.0.1 has zoom in / out buttons in the browser.

Comment: I just took a look but didn't see them.  Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the screenshot as comments don't support.

Comment: Ah, there you go!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use your browzer zoom.

e.g. CTRL + and CTRL - for Chrome

[Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en-GB)

[IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/zoom-webpage#1TC=windows-7)

[Safari](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19288?locale=en_GB)

Answer (score 2):

One of the best visualisations for graphs is KeyLines http://keylines.com/, however its not particularly cheap!

This allows zoom in/out and very sophisticated styling of your graph

Comment: Ah, right, thanks!  I knew that there was a Linkurious alternative but couldn't remember what it was ;)

Answer (score 1):

One neat little trick i've been using is to right-click on the canvas, find the top-level SVG element that looks something like this (on the latest Neo4j browser):

```
transform="translate(0,0)"
```

and change it to:

```
transform="scale(0.1)"
```